# Performance Issue to get value from excel and load it into dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void btnImportFromxls_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application myapp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = myapp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\MyExcel.xls");
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Dictionary<object, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        for (int i = 1; i < sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            object key = ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 1]).Value2;
            object value = ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 2]).Value2;

            dictionary.Add(key,value);
        }
    }
```

The excel file(MyExcel.xls) having 8,000 rows of data. when i try to load the data into dictionary with above code, It is taking long time to load the excel data into dictionary. is there any other way to speed up the loading data into dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

Faster than iterating through all cells in range is this:

```
using XLS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

object[,] arrWks;
object objKom;
string strKom;

arrWks = (object[,])sheet.UsedRange.get_Value(XLS.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

for (int intRow=arrWks.GetLowerBound(0); intRow<=arrWks.GetUpperBound(0); intRow++)
{
    for (int intCol=arrWks.GetLowerBound(1); intCol<=arrWks.GetUpperBound(1); intCol++)
    {
        objKom = arrWks[intRow, intCol];
        strKom = objKom == null ? "" : objKom.ToString();       

        //do rest of your logic here
    }
}
```

Instead of iterating entire arrWks, you could iterate only through specified columns, too.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. brief me with my code please.

Comment: This code loads entire UsedRange range of enuWorkshet(sheet in your example) to object[,] array. Then you can iterate the in-memory array, and you'll see it's much faster.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this with my code. help me out please.

Comment: Ok, I modified my initial code. This should be enough to get a grip.